# Failed to install 'cordova-plugin-accountkit' in ionic cordova platform ios

Tags: ios, ionic-framework, account-kit

I am trying to add account-Kit plugin into iOS build but it is showing an error.
Referring from : https://github.com/gurisko/cordova-plugin-accountkit
attached screenshot of terminal.

[image]

Comment: Did you tried to  reinstalling Cordova.
 using 
`npm uninstall -g cordova`
`npm install -g cordova`

Comment: Yes @core114 i did ,but same error

Answer (score 0):

Since its an ios build, its most like an cocoapods issue.

Remove platform ios `ionic cordova platform rm ios`

Install cocoapods from [here](http://%20https://guides.cocoapods.org/using/getting-started).

Once done run `pod setup`

Add platform ios `ionic cordova platform add ios`

Install the plugin

Run `pod install` (within platforms/ios)